# How to redirect after Nodemailer POST request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, nodemailer

I have an app with a React frontend, and an Express backend. I have a form setup with Nodemailer that sends an email after the user submits the form. I want to trigger a redirect after submission depending on whether the email was sent successfully or not. The emails send just fine, however the redirect does not. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**Post Request Handler**

```
app.post('/sendApplication', cpUpload, async (req) => {
    await sendMail(req.files['essay'][0], req.files['recLetter1'][0], req.files['recLetter2'][0], req.body)
})
```

**Nodemailer Code (My mail options are also here, but I omitted them since they're irrelevant)**

```
const sendMail = async () => {
    
        await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
                res.sendStatus(500)
            } else {
                console.log("Message Sent " + info.response)
                res.sendStatus(200)
            }
        })
}
```

**Front End Code**

```
handleRedirect = (res) => {
    if (res.status === 200) {
        this.props.history.push('/success')
    } else {
        this.props.history.push('/applicationerror')
    }
}

handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let formData = new FormData()
    for (let i in this.state.formValues) {
        formData.append(i, this.state.formValues[i])
    }
    formData.append('essay', document.getElementById('essay').files[0])
    formData.append('recLetter1', document.getElementById('recLetter1').files[0])
    formData.append('recLetter2', document.getElementById('recLetter2').files[0])
    fetch('/sendApplication', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    }).then((res) => {
        this.handleRedirect(res)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in this code:

1. Your route handler is the one that has access to the response stream, if you declare `sendMail` out of your handler, it has no idea what `res` is.
2. `transporter.sendMail` does not return a Promise, hence you can't await it, but you still can promisify it.
3. You are passing the files taken from `multer` and the `body` of the request to `sendMail` but it's not actually taking any parameter in.

```
app.post('/sendApplication', cpUpload, async (req) => {
try {
      await sendMail()
      res.sendStatus(200)
     } catch(e){
      console.log(e)
      res.sendStatus(500)
     }
})
```

**sendMail**

```
const sendMail = () => {
    ...
    ...
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err) {
        if (err) reject(err)
        else resolve()
      })
    })
}
```

4. You shoud not use `history.push` to change route, but something like `react-router` to perform client-side navigation.